# 1gb vs 10gb uplink in terms of TTFB

Tags: linux, web-server, performance, linux-networking, network-speed

I am about to setup a new dedicated server, I have the option of 1gb vs 10gb uplink with a considerable price difference. I do only have 10 domains on this sever and traffic is not huge. However, on my performance tests on my current server I have very low Time to First Byte (TTFB).

I wonder if this would be any improvement for TTFB if I chose 10bg instead of 1gb?

Comment: No a-priory reason why a 10 gigabit uplink would have a lower latency than a 1 gigabit uplink  (when you’re not using a significant percentage of that uplink. It *might* be different when your usual traffic patterns are close to saturating that 1 gigabit.) But some providers have different backbone networks associated with  different uplink tiers, each with different performance characteristics so don’t look only at the price

Comment: @HermanB thank you for the answer. I thought that there might not be a difference to the latency, but I was not sure. But your point that they might use different providers for different uplinks is a very valid point as well. I will look deeper into this so that I choose the best one.

Comment: [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization). try with 1Gbit uplink first and monitor your usage. use website and log analytics to determine if you need to upgrade. anyway, would a very low TTFB a good thing though?